# jQuery - json parse

Tags: jquery, json, parsing

How to use foreach parse the json type -

```
getData: function(id, dataid)
    {
        $.post('Action/Load.php',{
            id: id
        }, function(data) {
            
            $(dataid).html(data);
        });
    }
```

data = `{"file":"1","text":"Hello world","name":"Jenan","id":"1","url":"url"}`

I would get text -

```
1 - Hello World - Jenan - 1 - url.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$.each()` function only works on Arrays and jQuery objects.

Here, `data` is not an array, its a regular object.

So, get the data from your Json this way :

```
getData: function(id, dataid)
    {
        $.post('Action/Load.php',{
            id: id
        }, function(data) {
            $(dataid).html(data.file +' - '+ data.text +' - '+ data.name +' - '+ data.id +' - '+ data.url);
        });
    }
```

***EDIT:***
If you have some of these objects in an Array like the one that follows :

```
[{"file":"1","text":"Hello world","name":"Jenan","id":"1","url":"url"},{"file":"1","text":"Hello world","name":"Jenan","id":"1","url":"url"},{"file":"1","text":"Hello world","name":"Jenan","id":"1","url":"url"}]
```

Do like that :

```
getData: function(id, dataid)
    {
        $.post('Action/Load.php',{
            id: id
        }, function(data) {
            $(dataid).html('');
            $.each(data, function(key, value){
                $(dataid).append(value.file +' - '+ value.text +' - '+ value.name +' - '+ value.id +' - '+ value.url +'<br/>');
            });
        });
    }
```

Comment: And if I had a collection of data. How can I read only the url?

Comment: What do you mean by a collection of data ? Show me the Json representation of what you have in mind

Comment: I try your example and this is result - undefined - undefined - undefined - undefined - undefined

Comment: For example this collection : [
      {"value": "New", "onclick": "CreateNewDoc()"},
      {"value": "Open", "onclick": "OpenDoc()"},
      {"value": "Close", "onclick": "CloseDoc()"}
    ]

Comment: alright, then you need a `$.each()`, try with the updated code

Answer (score 2):

[**for...in**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) will loop through each object key:

```
var output = [];
for( var key in data) {
  if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      output.push(data[key])
  }
}

alert(output.join(' - '));
```

---

**EDIT**

```
data.url; // the value of url, which happens to be url in this example
// or
data['url']
```

[hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) ensures that the key is a direct property of the object.

Comment: +1 for suggesting Array.join. It's simpler, and more efficient than string concatenation.